# laravel 5.3: HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3

route:

```
  Route::post('serial', 'HomeController@serial');

  Route::get('doctorlist',['as'=>'doctorlist','uses'=>'HomeController@doctorlist']);
```

script:

```
 @section('scripts')

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        src = "{{ route('doctorlist') }}";
        $("#search_text").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);

                    }
                });
            },
            min_length: 3,

        });
    });
</script>
```

controller:

```
public function doctorlist(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->get('term','');

    $doctors=Doctors::where('doctors_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

    $data=array();
    foreach ($doctors as $doctor) {
        $data[]=array('value'=>$doctor->doctors_name,'id'=>$doctor->serial_no);
    }
    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
}
```

it always goes to serial route. not going doctorlist

Comment: Seriously C# :o . Laravel and c# ? Please remove that tag from your question

Comment: sorry for mistake

Comment: try like this {{url('doctorlist')}}

Comment: console it and check what it returns

Comment: it returns http://doctorserial.dev/serial?query=  but it should be http://doctorserial.dev/doctorlist?query because i write the query on doctorlist function

Comment: at last solved the problem.